# how to sum all records in SQL subquery to retrieve sum of all records?

Tags: sql, sum, subquery

I'm coding a query to retrieve sum of all components price used to make a product, but I have a problem with this query. WHen I code a query to retrieve the price of each component (quantity used * unit price) I retrieve the correct result:

```
SELECT t1.coc_codigo, SUM(t1.pmc_precio) * SUM(t2.ccm_cantidad)
FROM   precios_componentes_costos t1
JOIN   composicion_tipos_masa t2
ON     (t1.coc_codigo = t2.coc_codigo)
WHERE  t1.coc_codigo IN (SELECT coc_codigo
                         FROM   composicion_tipos_masa t3
                         JOIN   tipos_masas t4
                         ON    (t3.tms_codigo =t4.tms_codigo)
                         WHERE  t3.tms_codigo = 'MMS')
GROUP BY t1.coc_codigo
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

[image]
[image]

But when I try to summarized all records I retrieve a wrong result:

```
SELECT SUM(t1.pmc_precio) * SUM(t2.ccm_cantidad) AS TOTAL
FROM   precios_componentes_costos t1
JOIN   composicion_tipos_masa t2
ON     (t1.coc_codigo = t2.coc_codigo)
WHERE  t1.coc_codigo IN (SELECT coc_codigo
                         FROM   composicion_tipos_masa t3
                         JOIN   tipos_masas t4
                         ON    (t3.tms_codigo =t4.tms_codigo)
                         WHERE  t3.tms_codigo = 'MMS')
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

[image]

I would like to retrieve the final result with a query (195.591132). Do you have any idea? Thanks!.

Comment: If this is Oracle, what are the `mysql` and `sql-server` tags for?

Comment: because I think it can be solved using standar sql.

Comment: I think [`sql`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) is the tag for "standard SQL", if there is such a thing.

Comment: sorry, Now I will edit the post

Comment: Anyway, the query looks fine (for the grand total you removed the `t1.coc_codigo` from the `select` list and got rid of the `group by`, which is correct.) Unless anyone else spots anything you'll need to post a test case.

Comment: but why the result of the second query is wrong?

Comment: Your math assumption is wrong. Sum of products is not equal to product of sums. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/958771

Comment: "Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL." I.e. what most people call ANSI SQL.

Answer (score 1):

In agreement with the observation from @PM77-1, you need to perform the calculation for each record before you get the sum.  Something like this:

```
SELECT
    coc_codigo
  , SUM(TOTAL_SUB) AS TOTAL
FROM (
    SELECT
          t1.coc_codigo
        , (t1.pmc_precio * t2.ccm_cantidad) AS TOTAL_SUB
    FROM precios_componentes_costos t1
    INNER JOIN composicion_tipos_masa t2
        ON ( t1.coc_codigo = t2.coc_codigo )
    INNER JOIN composicion_tipos_masa t3
        ON ( t3.tms_codigo = t1.coc_codigo )
    INNER JOIN tipos_masas t4
        ON ( t3.tms_codigo = t4.tms_codigo )
    WHERE t3.tms_codigo = 'MMS'
    GROUP BY t1.coc_codigo
 ) AS multiplied
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally the comment from @PM77-1 made I remake my query and the new query is:

```
SELECT /*t1.coc_codigo,*/ SUM(t1.pmc_precio * t2.ccm_cantidad)
FROM   precios_componentes_costos t1
JOIN   composicion_tipos_masa t2
ON     (t1.coc_codigo = t2.coc_codigo)
WHERE  t1.coc_codigo IN (SELECT coc_codigo
                         FROM   composicion_tipos_masa t3
                         JOIN   tipos_masas t4
                         ON    (t3.tms_codigo =t4.tms_codigo)
                         WHERE  t3.tms_codigo = 'MMS')
--GROUP BY t1.coc_codigo
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

This query is correct!!! Thanks everyone for your help.